# Tomcat 7 IllegaMonitorStateException

Tags: tomcat, locking

We are using Tomcat 7.x.

Occasionally we are getting the following error (these are AJAX requests):

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:363)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1317)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:745)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:464)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

The method that fails is ContainerBase.getRealm().

In the case if this is Tomcat bug, how can we exclude the Authenticator Base from the Pipeline. Our application does not use any form of container managed security, i.e. we are not using Realms and  configurations in the web.xml.

The Tomcat documentation for the AuthenticatorBase class states:

“…..Basic implementation of the Valve interface that enforces the  elements in the web application deployment descriptor. This functionality is implemented as a Valve so that it can be ommitted in environments that do not require these features. Individual implementations of each supported authentication method can subclass this base class as required…..”

So if that is the only option at the moment, how can we omit this Valve from the pipeline?

Comment: You claim the problem is happening in ContainerBase.getRealm() but there is no sign of that method in your stack trace. Please provide the full, unedited stack trace. It would also help folks made sense of the line numbers if you provided the exact Tomcat version you are using.

Comment: This is the full stack trace returned from Tomcat. It is not edited. The line 464 in AuthenticatorBase invokes 'context.getRealm()'. The method getRealm() in ContainerBase is the one that uses ReentrantReadWriteLock. The problem sometimes occurs when unlocking the read lock in the finally clause. It is very strange what happens and why that thread does not hold the lock at that point. In our configuration we do not use any Tomcat realm so we have recursion of 3 getRealm() calls that finally return null.

Comment: The Tomcat version is 7.0.42.

Comment: There is no context.getRealm() call anywhere near line 464 in AuthenticatorBase for Apache Tomcat 7.0.42.

Comment: In tomcat 7.0.26 the line is 464. In Tomcat 7.0.42 it is the line 494. No matter of the line number it is: ' Realm realm = this.context.getRealm();' that produces the error. We have patched the unlocking logic and the error has gone. However I'm still confused if this is Tomcat bug or not.

Comment: What has Tomcat 7.0.26 got to do with this? You stated you are using 7.0.42.

Comment: Mr. Thomas, the exception is also present in Tomcat 7.0.53. The line and the version is not relevant.

Comment: What is relevant is your inability to provide correct information. When stack traces are incomplete, line numbers don't match the version you are claiming to be using and you keep changing your mind about the version being used it is hard to believe that any of the information being provided is correct.

Comment: If that makes you happy ok… What you see above is complete stack trace produced from your code (Tomcat 7.0.26). No matter if you agree or not the bug is still out there (Tomcat 7.0.53).